# Should I NOT put a bootstrap table inside of a DIV with the bootstrap 'row' class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I put a bootstrap table inside of a bootstrap row.  I've assumed that *everything* needed to be enclosed in a DIV element with a bootstrap class 'row'.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="idMyTbl" class="table table-striped">
      <thead id='idTblHead'></thead>
      <tbody id="idTblBody"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, now I'm wondering if that's actually a bad idea.  I haven't seen any documentation, that puts a table inside of a DIV tag that is a bootstrap row.  I haven't seen any behavior difference between putting the table in a row, but it seems unnecessary, as the table has it's own behavior that I'd think would be independent of a bootstrap row class.

Is it better to use the following HTML structure?

```
<div class="table-responsive" id='idTableList' style='display:none'>
  <table id="idMyTbl" class="table table-striped">
    <thead id='idTblHead'></thead>
    <tbody id="idTblBody"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is the 'row' class unnecessary with a table?  Will I get some unexpected result if I don't put a table inside of a bootstrap row?

Comment: Is a row required? No. Is it unheard of? No. Using a row takes advantage of Bootstrap's grid and which allows you to create horizontal groups of columns. If you don't need them, then you don't need a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary. `row`s are only necessary when using the column (`col-*-*`) classes of Bootstrap's grid system.